# Verilog pipeline

Tags: verilog, fpga

I'm trying to make a easy game using HD44780 LCD. 
My idea is to use a BUSY signal to hold off any commands until previous command is executed. I want to use counter and case for sequences of commands while another block is holded by BUSY signal.

Something like this:

```
    case (counter)
    0: CMD_REG = CLEAR_LCD;
    1: CMD_REG = WRITE_PLR;
    2: ME_BUSY = 0;
    endcase

    if(DRIVER_BUSY == 0 && counter < 2) begin
        ENABLE_DRIVER <= 1;
        counter <= counter + 1;
    end
    if (counter > 2) begin
        counter <= 4'd0;
    end
```

But it feels "wrong". I dont have any serious experience with Verilog so can someone tell me how it should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your idea seems fine, it might be better to use an Finite State Machine [FSM] ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine ). Pretty much this just means that instead of a counter, you would have a variable holding a series of states with more human readable names. Using this, you need only have a case statement defining your next state and output logic depending on the current state.

While this FSM will basically be implemented as a counter, its much easier to read. I cant tell exactly how to make it would with your code, but it might look something like this:

```
// State register
always @(posedge clk) begin
  state <= next_state;
end

// Next state and output logic
always @(*) begin
  // Default values
  CMD_REG = CLEAR_LCD;
  ME_BUSY = 1'b0;
  ENABLE_DRIVER = 1'b0;

  next_state = WAIT; // Im using enum style, but if you cant use enums, you can always use macros (`WAIT)

  case (state)
    WAIT: begin // counter == 0
      if (DRIVER_BUSY == 0) begin
        next_state = WAIT_MORE;
      end
    WAIT_MORE: begin // counter == 1
      ENABLE_DRIVER = 1'b1;
      CMD_REG = WRITE_PLR;

      if (DRIVER_BUSY == 0) begin
        next_state = NOT_BUSY_HOLD;
      end
    NOT_BUSY_HOLD: begin // counter == 2, here it looks like you get stuck due to your conditionals (at counter == 2, it doesnt increment nor reset)
      ...
```

But you get the idea hopefully.